# Get resource from another folder in Java

Tags: properties, inputstream, filepath, fileinputstream

My project has a folder for resource and a folder for src. All my code are in src and all my property files are in resource (it's set as resource root too)

So I want to read xyz.properties in my code as input stream

I tried

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/xyzz.properties");
```

and

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("xyzz.properties");
```

and neither worked. They all end up being null - only when I move xyzz.properties to the package that has the class that uses the above code does the second code snippet work. What should I be using for the path if I want to keep the current location of the property file?

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("xyzz.properties");
```

Or like this

```
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream("xyzz.properties");
```